# How to send username and password from client to server in C# socket programming

Tags: c#, sockets

I need to know how I should send username and password from a client to the server. Should they be send in separate streams or should I combine them in one stream and then send them to the client? and in which format should I send them?

Let's say the username is "user1" and the password is "123". this is one way that I think is good to do the job.

```
        var networkStream = TcpClient.GetStream();
        byte[] buffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("user1");
        networkStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        networkStream.Flush();
        var networkStream = TcpClient.GetStream();
        byte[] buffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("123");
        networkStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        networkStream.Flush();
```

The other way is to send the username and password in this way:

```
        var networkStream = TcpClient.GetStream();
        byte[] buffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("user1;123");
        networkStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        networkStream.Flush();
```

Which way is correct and is there any better approach?

And the other thing is how should the server know that the incoming stream is user and/or password?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to come up with a protocol that both ends understand. It's all up to you.

Comment: So you mean there is no standard approach to do it?

Comment: No, not if you're using plain sockets. (afaik) There are other ways to communicate though: remoting, wcf, soap, http